# Will we be able to burn arduino zero pro's bootloader?

Tags: bootloader

As arduino.org states, the bootloader is pre-burnt by Atmel at the factory. I'd like to know if it will be possible for us to buy "raw" ICs and burn them at home for our own boards, as we do with the Atmega328 for example.

Comment: Burning shouldn't be a problem. Though you might need a JTAG programmer.

Comment: My worry isnt that much about the hardware itself but the availability of the bootloader/firmware..

Comment: I can't seem to find it. Though my guess it that it will become available, since it's open source hardware/software. The bootloader might however depend on the onboard debug chip.

Comment: Hopefully it will be possible. Afaik with Due's its impossible because part of the firmware is burnt by Atmel at the factory..

Comment: That's interesting. I didn't know that.